# Representing optional syntax and repetition with OcamlYacc / FsYacc

Tags: f#, parsing, ocaml, ocamlyacc, fsyacc

I'm trying to build up some skills in lexing/parsing grammars. I'm looking back on a simple parser I wrote for SQL, and I'm not altogether happy with it -- it seems like there should have been an easier way to write the parser.

SQL tripped me up because it has a lot of optional tokens and repetition. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.ID = t3.ID
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
INNER JOIN t3 on t1.ID = t3.ID
```

The `ON` and `WHERE` clauses are optional and can occur more than once. I handled these in my parser as follows:

```
%{
open AST
%}

// ...    
%token <string> ID   
%token AND OR COMMA
%token EQ LT LE GT GE
%token JOIN INNER LEFT RIGHT ON
// ...

%%

op: EQ { Eq } | LT { Lt } | LE { Le } | GT { Gt } | GE { Ge }

// WHERE clause is optional    
whereClause:
    |                       { None }
    | WHERE whereList       { Some($2) }        

whereList:
    | ID op ID                    { Cond($1, $2, $3) }
    | ID op ID AND whereList      { And(Cond($1, $2, $3), $5) }
    | ID op ID OR whereList       { Or(Cond($1, $2, $3), $5) }


// Join clause is optional    
joinList:
    |                       { [] }
    | joinClause            { [$1] }
    | joinClause joinList   { $1 :: $2 }

joinClause:
    | INNER JOIN ID joinOnClause    { $3, Inner, $4 }
    | LEFT JOIN ID joinOnClause     { $3, Left, $4 }
    | RIGHT JOIN ID joinOnClause    { $3, Right, $4 }

// "On" clause is optional    
joinOnClause:
    |                       { None }
    | ON whereList          { Some($2) }

// ...
%%
```

In other words, I handled optional syntax by breaking it into separate rules, and handled repetition using recursion. This works, but it breaks parsing into a bunch of little subroutines, and it's very hard to see what the grammar actually represents.

I think it would be much easier to write if I could specify optional syntax inside brackets and repetition with an * or +. This would reduce my whereClause and joinList rules to the following:

```
whereClause:
    |                       { None }
//    $1    $2, I envision $2 being return as an (ID * op * ID * cond) list
    | WHERE [ ID op ID { (AND | OR) }]+
        { Some([for name1, op, name2, _ in $1 -> name1, op, name2]) }

joinClause:
    |                       { None }

//    $1, returned as (joinType
//                       * JOIN
//                       * ID
//                       * ((ID * op * ID) list) option) list
    | [ (INNER | LEFT | RIGHT) JOIN ID [ON whereClause] ]*
        { let joinType, _, table, onClause = $1;
          Some(table, joinType, onClause) }
```

I think this form is **much** easier to read and expresses the grammar it's trying to capture more intuitively. Unfortunately, I can't find anything in either the Ocaml or F# documentation which supports this notation or anything similar.

**Is there an easy way to represent grammars with optional or repetitive tokens in OcamlYacc or FsYacc?**

Comment: My SQL is rusty, but I seem to remember that use of ON or WHERE is not strictly equivalent in all cases (for outer joins, if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 4):

[Menhir](http://cristal.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/) allows to parametrize nonterminal symbols by another symbols and provides the library of standard shortcuts, like optionals and lists, and you can create your own. Example:

```
option(X): x=X { Some x} 
         | { None }
```

There is also some syntax sugar, 'token?' is equivalent to 'option(token)', 'token+' to 'nonempty_list(token)'.

All of this really shortens grammar definition. Also it is supported by ocamlbuild and can be a drop-in replacement for ocamlyacc. Highly recommended!

Funny, I used it to parse SQL too :)

Answer (score 3):

When you compose all the little pieces you should get something like you want though. Instead of:

```
(INNER | RIGHT | LEFT )
```

you just have

```
inner_right_left
```

and define that to be the union of those three keywords.

You can also define the union in the lexer. in the way you define the tokens, or using camlp4, I haven't done much in that area, so I cannot advise you to take those routes. And I don't think they'll work for you as well as just having little pieces everywhere.

*EDIT:*

So, for camlp4 you can look at [Camlp4 Grammar module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-camlp4/manual005.html) and a [tutorial](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/tutorial-camlp4/tutorial003.html) and a [better tutorial](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Full_parser_tutorial). This isn't *exactly* what you want, mind you, but it's pretty close. The documentation is pretty bad, as expressed in the [recent discussion on the ocaml groups](http://groups.google.com/group/fa.caml/browse_thread/thread/733c0846d6d2ead5#), but for this specific area, I don't think you'll have too many problems. I did a little with it and can field more questions.